# anti-virus software and Flash's AVHardwareDisable

Tags: flash, virus, anti-virus

[This site](http://risonhuang.wordpress.com/2009/08/07/flash-player-privacy-settings-dialog-disabled/) claims that

> [The AVHardwareDisable setting] in flash configuration file has been changed by
>   anti-virus software

which disables camera/microphone access for all sites.  The article goes on to discuss how to fix this setting, but doesn't detail *which anti-virus products* change this setting.  I'd like to know which anti-virus products do this.

Comment: Well when I Google for [`AVHardwareDisable antivirus`](https://www.google.com/search?q=AVHardwareDisable+antivirus), aside from your question here and the blog post you linked to, none of the other results seem to be relevant. Similarly, Googling for `flash antivirus camera` and `flash antivirus microphone` don’t bring up any pages of features of any antivirus. I suppose that it *could* be a function of some security software when you set the level to high-security, but I can’t find any that actually do (or at least none that mention it).

Comment: I just took the (obvious?) step and simply added [a comment](http://risonhuang.wordpress.com/2009/08/07/flash-player-privacy-settings-dialog-disabled/comment-page-1/#comment-7) to the blog post to *ask* the author. `;-)`